# manually change wrong Url of browser in angular6?

Tags: angular, routes

```
http://localhost:4200/base/editlanguagedetails/25
```

this is my right url that time UI is like this[image]

now i change wrong url manually in browser like this `http://localhost:4200/base/editlanguagedetails/5256`

that time UI is [image]

app-routing.component.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path : 'base', component : BaseComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardGuard],runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
   children: [
     { path: 'newlanguage', component : NewLanguageComponent},
     { path: 'editlanguagedetails/:id', component : languageComponent},
   ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]
```

so, my query is when i change wrong url manually that time i dont want to show UI. so what is solution for this(it is possible when manually change wrong url that time redirect on any specific page) give me helpful solution thank you.

Comment: i think 25 and 5256 are parameters not part of the url. right ?

Comment: i edit my code it is part of url

Comment: `:id` is parameter so it won't be detected as url change it will only be seen as parameter change that is why it is not returning the image and the country name in the second url

Comment: @hana_wujira any solution for this to redirect on onether page when put wrong url

Comment: you can redirect to other page from your component file after checking whether it is valid id or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle all the routes and redirect to some page not found page when the route path is incorrect, by introducing below code.

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path : 'base', component : BaseComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardGuard],runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
   children: [
    { path: 'editlanguagedetails/:id', component : languageComponent},
   ]
 },
 { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
 ]
```

This way you don't have to worry about other incorrect routes.

Note: PageNotFoundComponent is not an inbuilt component, it has to be created by us

Comment: see my edited app-routing.component.ts code it is work for newlanguagecomponent but not works for languagecompnent

Comment: :id is a data, as part of route path, so that has to be handled manually. The source from where you are fetching image, if that source/service returns no information, then you have to explicitly redirect them to the required page. Check https://angular.io/guide/router url in this, look for CrisisDetailComponent and search for "this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center']) ". You will understand the example. Basically you have to do it manually, angular will not understand it automatically.